# How would I destroy all Clones created - Roblox

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

How would I destroy all GUI Clones created - Roblox

I've spent hours haven't found a reason to why it's not working.

```
function Notification(container, title, text, image)
    local newNotification = container:Clone()

    container.Enabled = true
    container.Frame.titleText.Text = title
    container.Frame.descriptionText.Text = text
    container.Frame.ImageLabel.Image = image
end

function Remove()
    script.Parent:destroy()
end

Notification(game.StarterGui.RampageInterface.LoadNotification, "RAMPAGE", "Rampage Notification System", "rbxassetid://7072707452")
wait(3)
Remove()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what isn't working? What do you want to happen, what is actually happening? Are any errors showing up? Is this a LocalScript? Where is this code located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can use the destroy command or there is a instance command `Instance:ClearAllChildren()`

`Instance:Destroy()`

I may be wrong about this but try it out.
[https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/ClearAllChildren](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/ClearAllChildrenhttps://)

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/Destroy